# Is there a way to mass localize audio files in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xcode6

I'm localizing an iOS app that contains hundreds of audio files. I have not found a way to localize them without clicking the file, clicking "Localize" in the inspector, clicking the language for the localization and clicking the second language localization checkbox. That's a whole lot of clicks. There has to be a better way. 
Xcode won't let me multi-select several files and have the "Localize" button enabled. I also tried fooling Xcode by quitting, moving the audio files into the two localization directories, and reopening the project. No go. 
Ideas?

Comment: You may have other problems if your app contains hundreds of audio files such as the 4GB app submission limit.

Comment: Thanks. They're short clips so the app is under 100 MB.

Comment: It works so if you add new localization. You can remove some localization from Xcode and add it back again. Don't click to delete localized files itself, Xcode can reuse them when you switch localization on again

Comment: That's a good suggestion and I suspect it will work. I'll have to setup a test and report back on whether that works.

Comment: @Azat I gave that a try and it didn't work as desired. When I added the localization back into the project it prompted me if I wanted to localize only the assets that I had manually localized previously. It didn't give the option of localizing the bundled assets I hadn't manually localized previously.